# Remove command from a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
    b1=Button(bla bla bla,command=run_something)

    b1.configure (command='')
```

I want to remove the 'command' from a button so that if pressed nothing happens

how would I do this?

note:
I did not use the b1.bind(<"button-1">)
no I cant change it to this and then use b1.unbind

Comment: Any particular widget toolkit?

Comment: i dont know what you mean by that sorry

Comment: @ilovecrysis: What is `Button`? Where did you import it from?

Comment: from tkinter import *

Comment: What you wrote works for me. `b1.configure(command='')`, `b1.configure(command=lambda:None)`, etc. should all work.

Answer (score 1):

Set the command to `None`:

```
b1.config(command=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could write a function which does nothing and assign it to that button maybe.

Comment: Having a command interferes with manual bindings so the command has to be removed completely rather than just do nothing.